# File upload progress in Flutter using BLoC

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to upload an image to a node.js backend and show the progress bar while the image is uploading. I am using flutter_bloc for state management.

How do I yield the progress state from the callback function inside the bloc class?

Is there any other way to send the progress state back to the UI class using BLoC?

Below is my image upload function code:

```
static Stream<FileUploadEvent> uploadImageMultiPart({File file}) async* {
  assert(file != null);

  final url = '${Api.apiUrl}upload';
  final httpClient = getHttpClient();
  final request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));

  int byteCount = 0;

  var multipart = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
    "image",
    file.path,
    contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpeg'),
  );

  var requestMultipart = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(url));
  requestMultipart.files.add(multipart);

  var msStream = requestMultipart.finalize();

  var totalByteLength = requestMultipart.contentLength;
  request.contentLength = totalByteLength;

  request.headers.set(
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, requestMultipart.headers[HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader]);
  request.headers.add("hosturl", Api.baseUrl);

  Stream<List<int>> streamUpload = msStream.transform(
    new StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (data, sink) {
        sink.add(data);
        byteCount += data.length;

        // I WANT TO YIELD THE PROGRESS EVENT FROM HERE FROM HERE

        // yield FileUploadProgress(progress: byteCount);

      },
      handleError: (error, stack, sink) {
        throw error;
      },
      handleDone: (sink) {
        sink.close();
        // UPLOAD DONE;
      },
    ),
  );

  await request.addStream(streamUpload);

  final httpResponse = await request.close();
  var statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;

  if (statusCode ~/ 100 != 2) {
    throw Exception('Error uploading file, Status code: ${httpResponse.statusCode}');
  } else {

  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @AxesGrinds I managed to implement the upload progress functionality using Stream, StreamController and StreamTransformer.